JMX exporter stops working after sometime and application starts getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Max number of active transactions reached:50
We enabled JMX exporter for tracking jmx metrics. What i have observed is, after an hour or so, grafana stops showing metrics and even the application which i am tracking starts leaving transactions open and stops with
ENGINE-14019 Exception during job acquisition Max number of active transactions reached:50
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Max number of active transactions reached:50
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionServiceImp.createCompositeTransaction(TransactionServiceImp.java:1002)
at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.BaseTransactionManager.createCompositeTransaction(BaseTransactionManager.java:439)
at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.begin(TransactionManagerImp.java:326)
at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.begin(TransactionManagerImp.java:303)
at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.begin(UserTransactionImp.java:116)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doJtaBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:875)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doBegin(JtaTransactionManager.java:832)

Check your atomikos JTA properties to see the value of com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives property. By default, it is set to 50. So you have to set it to a negative value to make it infinite or you can set any higher value to prevent the error.
You can also set it by the following function in spring boot application:
public void setMaxActives(int maxActivities)
See the docs for further help.
Springboot Atomikos
Atomikos JTA Properties
